# DSolve non linear DE

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

probably my problem i´m gonna ask seems ridiculous and quite basic.
I want to solve an equation with the following code, where a,b,c are parameters. But surprisingly they don´t appear in the solution. I guess, it´s my mistake but I don´t see what I have done wrong. For a quite similiar equation it worked quite well and they didn´t disappear. So here is my line:

```
DSolve[Derivative[1][r][t] == a*exp (-(b - (c*1/r[t])^0.5)), r[t], t]
```

Additionally, I wanted to know if there´s a easy way to get an parametric plot.
I would be very grateful if someone could give a hint!

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `Exp[..]` instead of `exp(..)`.  It's unclear what sort of parametric plot you seek, but there are examples of `ParametricPlot` in the `DSolve` documentation.  You could also look that the docs for `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Probably using `1/2` instead of `0.5` would help, if the DE is solvable.  There's a significant difference at times between an exact number `1/2` and a floating point number `0.5`, which is treated as an approximate real number.

Comment: Thanks for your introduction!
Unfortunately, the things you recommended didn't help. I am really surprised by this strange behaviour. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N7I7r.png), which seems ok -- has the parameters, etc.

Comment: What are the values for constants a, b, and c?

Answer (score 0):

I am completely surprised by this weird comportment but as Mathematica complaints that it is a list one can try to act in conformance

```
eq = r'[t] - a E^-(b - (c/r[t])^.5)
```

You may look at

```
eq[[1,1]]
```

and solve for

```
  DSolve[eq[[1, 1]] == 0, r[t], t]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But the thing, I want a general solution and dont want to put in already initial conditions. Especially, as i do not know the derivative condition. Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I found the answer for the "problem". Changing the parameters to capital letters (hopefully) solved the problem. Still I am not really sure about it. As I am not able to plot the result.

```
In[56]:= Solution ==  DSolve[{Derivative[1][r][t] == A*exp (-(B - (C*1/r[t])^(1/2))),  r[0] ==  D}, r[t], t]


Out[56]= Solution == {{r[t] -> InverseFunction[-((-2 C ArcTanh[B/Sqrt[C/#1]] + C Log[-C + B^2 #1] + B (B + 2 Sqrt[C/#1]) #1)/B^3) &][A exp t + (-B^2 D - 2 B Sqrt[C/D] D + 2 C ArcTanh[B/Sqrt[C/D]] -C Log[-C + B^2 D])/B^3]}}
```

At least this is a solution where my parameters appear. How do i plot this result now, as it contains a function handle.
I tried Plot(Solution,{t,0,1}) but this gives me the warning that there are not enough input arguments. Do I have to be careful with such handles?

Comment: Avoid using single capital letters for your variables (I avoid starting with capitals, too). For instance `C` and `D` are `Protected` system symbols that should never be used for variables. Also you still have `exp` instead of `Exp[]`; `exp` will be interpreted as a parameter/variable/constant having nothing to do with the exponential function. -- If you tried `Plot(Solution,{t,0,1})`, then you haven't been copying the examples from the documentation carefully. And if you don't give numeric values to the parameters, the solution will not evaluate to a real number and will not be plotted.